# why this code is not working in agda?

Tags: agda

I am trying to prove commutative property over natural number on multiplication operation.

```
--proving comm over *
*comm : ∀ a b → (a * b) ≡ (b * a)
*comm zero b = sym (rightId* b)
*comm (suc a) b = {!!}
```

when i check goal I found that it is `b + a * b ≡ b * suc a`. So i proved this.

```
lemma*-swap : ∀ a b → a + a * b ≡ a * suc b
```

Now when i tried :

```
*comm : ∀ a b → (a * b) ≡ (b * a)
*comm zero b = sym (rightId* b)
*comm (suc a) b = lemma*-swap b a
```

This should work as it satisfied the goal but why this is not working?? Please suggest me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`b + a * b` (the expression in the goal) and `a + a * b` (the expression in `lemma*-swap`) are distinct so applying `lemma*-swap` *does not* satisfy the goal.

You need to `rewrite` the induction hypothesis `*comm a b` to turn `a * b` into `b * a` in the goal so that the expression `lemma*-swap b a` can be used to discharge the goal.